# Windows 8.1 Change Win+S to Win

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, modern-ui

Is there a way to change win+s shortcut to only win?

I want this after pressing only one, win key

[image]

instead of whole metro UI.

Answer (score 3):

Just hit the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and start typing.

You won't see a search field on screen, before you start typing but it will appear. This is standard behaviour in Windows 8. There is no need to change anything.

Comment: One of my favourite features of Win8.x hehe :)

Comment: Yes, but it covers whole screen and win+s doesn't